# in sql convert time to timestamp

Tags: mysql, date

i have time like in ex: 10.45,13.00
now i need check that time as date in where

my query is

```
SELECT T.*,
  (SELECT a.driver_id
   FROM tbl_assigned_drivers a
   WHERE a.vehicle_id=t.id
     AND a.from_time<=T.time
     AND a.to_time >=T.time
     AND a.status='1') AS driver
FROM
  (SELECT id, user_id, stime AS TIME, splace, slat, slng, eplace, elat, elng, status, '1' AS TYPE
   FROM `tb_shifts`
   UNION ALL SELECT id, user_id, etime AS TIME, eplace AS splace, elat AS slat, elng AS slng, splace AS eplace, slat AS elat, slng AS elng, status, '0' AS TYPE
   FROM `tb_shifts`) T,
     tb_shft_veh s,
     tb_trucks_data t
WHERE T.time>=11.54
  AND s.register_number=t.register_number
  AND s.register_number='AP01TEST'
  AND s.shft_id=T.id
  AND s.status='1'
ORDER BY T.time ASC
```

here

```
a.from_time,a.to_time in format of "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"
T.time in format of "HH:MM"
```

Now i need convert that T.time into a.from_time format

Please Help me...

Comment: [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server] are two completely separate RDBMS products (with completely different datetime functionality). Pick one.

Comment: its completly  mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all,
Solved Query is

```
select T.*,(SELECT a.driver_id FROM tbl_assigned_drivers a WHERE a.vehicle_id=t.id and a.from_time<=CONCAT(CURDATE()," ",REPLACE(T.time, '.', ':'),":00") and a.to_time >=CONCAT(CURDATE()," ",REPLACE(T.time, '.', ':'),":00") and a.status='1') as driver from (SELECT id,user_id,stime as time,splace,slat,slng,eplace,elat,elng,status,'1' as type FROM `tb_shifts` UNION ALL SELECT id,user_id,etime as time,eplace as splace,elat as slat,elng as slng,splace as eplace,slat as elat,slng as elng,status,'0' as type FROM `tb_shifts`) T,tb_shft_veh s,tb_trucks_data t where T.time>=11.54 and s.register_number=t.register_number and s.register_number='AP01TEST' and s.shft_id=T.id and s.status='1' order by T.time asc
```

Solution will be from

```
CONCAT(CURDATE()," ",REPLACE("10.00", '.', ':'),":00")
```